# Añadir datos en una fila de una id

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, trigger

hola uso un script en laravel 5.8 quisiera agregar una columna para ver información en la tabla purchase_price que contenga la id, me comentaron que podría usar un disparador para esto pero no entiendo como funciona
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
purchase_lines Es una tabla aparte

Comment: Hola, ¿purchase_price es una columna en una tabla o una tabla aparte? Porque en la imagen está como un dato, no una tabla. También, ¿podrías especificar un poco más lo que necesitas?

Comment: Es una tabla aparte

Comment: Si mencionas laravel y dices tabla, suena a un elemento html `<table>`; pero si muestras una pantalla de phpMyAdmin y dices tabla, suena a una tabla de MySQL. ¿A qué tipo de tabla quieres agregar la columna?; tal vez si muestras algo de código (no en imágenes) se entienda.

Comment: me explico, el dato se encuentra en una tabla de mysql el dato señalado en mysql lo quiero implementar en el elemento html exactamente como señale la primera imagen no importa si no es editable... solo necesito que al llamar la id aparesca el valor correspondiente de purchase_price

Comment: Si no muestras algo de código se hace difícil ayudarte; ¿al llamar el id cómo, tienes algún proceso dinámico? ¿no lo estás logrando porque tienes algún error? ¿tienes esos modelos relacionados? si es así podrías llamar la relación en plan ``value="{{$variable->relación->purchase_price}}"``.

Comment: no funciona usando la relacion... tendria que crearla, no existe un codigo como tal por necesito crearlo y permitir la relacion o permitirle al controlador